# How save changed TextView with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences

OK here is my problem. I have a spinner and every option in spinner should edit textview in my layout (option in spinner you can see in position command), so I have made it with SharedPreferences, it is not problem, when I select some option in spinner, so the textview is changed, but when I kill my app and then re-open, the textview is default (the same as defined in my layout). So where is the problem?

**First Activity:**

```
if(position == 4){
    SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = CPUActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorUv = myPrefsUv.edit();
    prefsEditorUv.putString(maxUv, "1");
    prefsEditorUv.commit();
}

if(position == 5){
    SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = CPUActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorUv = myPrefsUv.edit();
    prefsEditorUv.putString(maxUv, "2");
    prefsEditorUv.commit();
}

if(position == 6){
    SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = CPUActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorUv = myPrefsUv.edit();
    prefsEditorUv.putString(maxUv, "3");
    prefsEditorUv.commit();
}

if(position == 7){
    SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = CPUActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorUv = myPrefsUv.edit();
    prefsEditorUv.putString(maxUv, "4");
    prefsEditorUv.commit();
}
```

**Second Activity:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = UVActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String prefNameUv = myPrefsUv.getString(maxUv, "");
        if(prefNameUv == "1"){
            final TextView textUv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_max);
            textUv.setText("100");
        }
        if(prefNameUv == "2"){
            final TextView textUv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_max);
            textUv.setText("110");
        }
        if(prefNameUv == "3"){
            final TextView textUv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_max);
            textUv.setText("120");
        }
        if(prefNameUv == "4"){
            final TextView textUv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_max);
            textUv.setText("130");
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. In addition to improving the loose speech, you should also provide the 1) current result/text, 2) expected result.

Comment: Edited. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the different values with the same key? This way I think it will always return the first match. I don't see in your code "maxUv" to be assigned different values, according to the different cases.

1) I suggest you move to if/else construct. This way, when you're in the right case, the remaining conditions are not evaluated.

2) call the following lines outside  the if/else construct. You don't need to get the SharedPreferences Editor in every case.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = CPUActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsUv", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditorUv = myPrefsUv.edit();
```

Same for the acquiring of `TextView textUv` in the second Activity. Just acquire reference once, and use the same reference in all cases.

3) In the second Activity, you're also comparing Strings with == operator, but Strings should be compared with [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Yes, of course I didn't noticed that, because I was overworked. So I edited my code, but still it is not solution, when I kill my app and then re-opn my SharedPreferences have lost. Any solution?

Comment: You beat me to it. That's why I generally avoid answering questions early morning! :-)

Comment: late office hours here :) 18:20PM.

Comment: Thanks, but it's just luck. I answered yesterday and didn't noticed it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now when I have used equals, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The other guy beat me to it. the old equals stuff.

You're comparing a String using "==". You should compare using .equals:

```
if(prefNameUv.equals("1"))
```

***This is what you need.***

Besides, try not to declare the preferences file. In your case, you're not needing it, so there is no need to make it more complex. Use the following...

First activity:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CPUActivity.this);
```

Second activity:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefsUv = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UVActivity.this);
```

Comment: Replace that when you create the variables in the two activities and see if it works. And try to use "else" on the if blocks next time.

Comment: Yes, as I was saying, the problem was only in equals, thanks.